# solr query without order

Tags: solr

I have a solr index with the unique field as "id".

I have a ordered set of ids, using which I would like to query Solr. But I want the results in the same order.

so for example if i have the ids id = [5,1,3,4] I want the results displayed in solr in same order.

I tried `http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=id:(5 OR 1 OR 3 OR 4)&fl=id`, but the results displayed are in ascending order.

Is their a way to query solr, and get results as I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't, 
The results appear in the order they are indexed unless you specify a default sort field or the explicit sort field/order.

Comment: Ok. Thanks [filling 15 char limit]

Answer (score 0):

You can add another field to keep the initial sort order. You then can sort=field asc to retrieve the data in the original order.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to query solr and sort the results in codes of yourself.